# iOS: WebView position not changing

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have a custom browser for which I am using webview. When the view controller loads, the webview is positioned at (0,40) from the above (the above 40 px are for the address bar). Now, when the user taps on the webview, I am making the address bar to remove itself from the screen and move the webview to the top of the screen (0,0). However, the webview sticks to the old position (0,40). Even I changed the origin.y to something big, but it still remains at the same location. The below code is how I am trying to move the webview.

```
webView.frame = CGRectMake(0,1000,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height);
    [self.view addSubview:webView];
```

Please let me know if there is any problem with the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
  myWeb.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
}
```

Working fine for me.

And you have to hide the other things like textField etc. or remove them from superView